# Columns display wierd naming after resetting multi index back to columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

So I have been working with a dataframe and converted it to long to wide setting a multi index.

`df_wide = df.pivot_table(index = ["StationId", "day", "month", "year", "hour", "dayofweek"], columns = "minute", values = ["StationTotalFlow"])`

I then used reset_index to reuse the columns I originally multi indexed.

```
df_wide = df_wide.reset_index()
```

My dataframe now looks like this(screenshot):

[dataframe screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov6nU.png)

I would like to remove that minute index and...
Using

```
df_wide.info()
```

I notice my column names are wrapped in parentheses.

[.info screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7V9q.png)

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Please do not post screenshots. Provide sample datasets for us to help better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that they're "wrapped in parentheses" really, it's that you went from a MultiIndex to a single-level list of names, so the first level of the MultiIndex became the first element of each tuple, and the second level became the second element of each tuple.

Comment: I am a little confused.  Are they not columns?  I would like to just make them columns again but keeping the pivot I did previously.  Thanks for the quick reply!